# JSF war file is automatically undeployed after deploying in to JBOSS 6.1 eap

Tags: jsf, deployment, war, after-create, undeploy

We are trying to deploy the JSF war in JBOSS 6.1 eap. But after deploying the war file,it is un-deploying. Even though we tried like remove the temp and log folder.But there is no use .after 10 minites,it is getting un-deployed. Please suggest me to fix this issue.

Comment: Does the application actually work in the 10 minute period?

Comment: Post the log output here